# Как IDEA собирает проект

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Где посмотреть скрипт сборки IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Idea может собирать проект по-разному. Что именно вам надо?
Но если вы новичек, то можно просто задать настройки для сборки проекта.

Comment: Надо посмотреть как она прописывает cpasspath

Comment: Что с ним не так. Напишите все сразу, доступно и полностью. Не вытягивать же из вас постоянно по одному предложению.

Comment: Просто хотелось знать как она это делает, точнее мне надо было в classpath добавить библиотеки из разных папок(не из репозитория) Думал это использовать в всоем maven проекте, но сейчас понял, что тут параллели проводить не уместно)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сгенерируйте Ant build и все увидите:

**Build->Generate Ant build...**